# Perl Programm keep waiting to open a file using utf8

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a UTF-8 encoded xml file. This file is of size around 8M and contains only one line.

I used below line to open this single line xml file:

```
open(INP,"<:utf8","$infile") or die "Couldn't open file passed as input, $!";
local $/ = undef;
my $inputfile = <INP>;
print $inputfile; ## Not working..
```

But after this line program get stuck and keep waiting.

I have tried other methods like binmode and decode but getting the same issue.

The same Program works when i change above mentioned file opening code to:

```
open(INP,"$infile") or die "Couldn't open file passed as input, $!";
local $/ = undef;
my $inputfile = <INP>;
print $inputfile; ## It works..


open(INP,"$infile") or die "Couldn't open file passed as input, $!";
binmode(INP, ":utf8");
local $/ = undef;
my $inputfile = <INP>;
print $inputfile; ## Not working..
```

Can you please help me what I am doing wrong here? I need to perform some operation on the input data and have to get utf8 encoded output.

Comment: Just updated the piece of code used..

Comment: hmmm, that should not matter at all.

Comment: wait, what line blocks when you use `decode`? Cause you you've just said that `my $if = <INP>;` blocks and `my $if = <INP>; decode('utf8', $if)` doesn't, and that makes absolutely NO sense.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to use the less space there.. have updated the code again. In the second case it get stuck when I use decode() there and it first case it works..

Comment: What version of perl are you using? Maybe it is not fresh enough?

Comment: ver 5.8.8 . When used a smaller part of input file after splitting it. I found same code working.. Not sure if this is memory issue.

Comment: 5.8.8 is old (seven years).  Can you upgrade?

Comment: Re "stuck when I use decode() there and it first case it works." I don't believe you. I think you are misanaylsing the situation. There's no reason two identical piece of code would behave differently because they're followed by different code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your last snippet here (Ubuntu 12.04, perl 5.14.2) and it works as expected. Only problem I have, is a difference between the input and output. Input file is UTF-8 and output is ISO-8859-1.

When I add

```
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
```

this problem is gone, though. So this must be an environment issue.